# How to sum previous n data that match pattern in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to sum previous n data that match pattern in Excel?

I will use the table below to simplify the problem.

[image: screenshot of table]

If 16 is chosen I want to sum the previous three prices of red apples (11,10,4).

It would be much easier to sum all the data that matches the pattern but i need the data to be the previous n-data.

Thanks.

Comment: It could not hurt to add to your question what version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `G2`, enter formula :

```
=SUM(INDEX(D1:D50,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A1:A50)/(C1:C50=LOOKUP(9^9,A1:A50,C1:C50)),{2,3,4})))))
```

[image]

Comment: wow thank you so much for the answer! although i am still learning it.
can you please explain the "LOOKUP(9^9" part?  Thanks

Comment: LOOKUP(9^9....), 9^9 we called Bignum, formula purpose is to return the last number. Please Google in searching for "Excel Bignum" for more details